# pip installs wrong platform of pywin32 into Embed Python

Tags: python, pip, pywin32

I uncompress Embed Python, download pip wheel extract it and put to lib\site-packages. Next run `python -m pip install pywin32`. So far so god. But when running program it fails to load `pywin32file.pyd`. With dependency walker I checked and realized it is x86 architecture while running x64 Python. I tried with x64 downloaded version of pywin32 wheel file and got error "`Unsupported platform`". pip installed x86 wheel but is is not correct.
At the end, I unzipped x64 version of pywin32 wheel into lib\site-packages. Two dlls from pywin32_system32 copied to dll search path and it works now.
We are distributing Embed Python with handful of libraries and pip is god way to get them.

What causes wrong architecture detection by pip and how to solve problem?

Comment: Where did you move those two dlls from pywin32_system32 ? C:\Windows\System32 ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you encountered may have had a different cause to my issue, but I was able to resolve a similar problem with pip installing 32-bit packages on 64-bit Python by changing my `VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH` environment variable from `x86` (which seems to be the default setting if you are using the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt or anything that relies on it) to `x86_64`.

This seems to be a [bug in packaging](https://github.com/pypa/packaging/issues/327) that was just fixed this April, so, as of this writing, the fix may not have yet made its way into pip.